# Issue with php array_sum displaying multiple values

Tags: php, function

I'm having an issue with with a PHP function displaying multiple sums instead of just one when I use `array_sum`. I'm using phpMyAdmin and the two database tables for this function. These are the tables:

games:

[image]

cart:

[image]

```
function total_price() {
    $total = 0; 
    global $con; 
    $ip = getIP(); 
    $select_price = "select * from cart where ip_add = '$ip'"; 
    $run_price = mysqli_query ($con, $select_price);
    while ($g_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) { 
        $Cart_Game_ID = $g_price['g_ID']; 
        $cart_price = "select * from games where Game_ID = '$Cart_Game_ID'";    
        $run_game_price = mysqli_query($con, $cart_price); 
        while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_game_price)){
            $Game_Price = array($pp_price['Game_Price']);  
            $values = array_sum($Game_Price);
            $total += $values; 
        }
    echo "$" . $total; 
    }

}
```

Every game in my database costs $20. There are currently 5 games in my database. When I run this function I get $20$40$60$80$100. All i need is the $100. Not the previous 4 sums.

Comment: Is this just for learning purposes? Otherwise, the sum calculation could be done with only one database query, with no `loops`, ...

Comment: Yea its to help understand how loops can be used to pull data from multiple databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this outside the While Loop:

```
echo "$" . $total;
```

Comment: Haha your welcome -  I know exactly how you feel, all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes

Comment: @underflow Haha, that's the programmer destiny xD